# How do I configure my Android.mk compilation to export all symbols by default for debug builds only?

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build

I have a native shared library (.so) in my app that I would like to run unit tests on.
In particular, there are several functions in my .so that I would like directly call from my unit tests.  However, I do not want these functions to be visible in the release version.

The way I'm currently planning to do this is to remove the -fvisibility=hidden compile option when building for debug (NDK_DEBUG=1).  However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this from the Android.mk file.

Here is my current Android.mk (a little simplified):

```
TARGET_PLATFORM := android-8
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := nuke_launcher
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := red_button.c abort_sequence.c

ifdef NDK_DEBUG
    LOCAL_CFLAGS := -fvisibility=default  # <-- Doesn't work
endif

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**default** (visible) is on by default; you probably want to set `LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fvisibility=hidden` for non-debug build.

Comment: Yes! You are right, it should be on by default.  And indeed, I look further down my Android.mk file and there I do see -fvisibility=hidden.  No wonder my code didn't work...  Thanks!